# Vertical list with horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css

Is it possible using a standard unordered list with a fixed height, to have overflowing elements flow into the next column.

Essentially I'm trying to achieve a magazine style layout where each article is stacked vertically.

Example code at http://jsfiddle.net/uDAJy/1/

I would expect the list items numbered 2, to be in the next column.

Thanks

Ben

#### Solution

I'm going to go down the CSS3 route that @Sime posted where possible.

For IE:

As the articles on the page are variable widths I couldn't find a clean solution without doing some server side programming.

This involved first calculating the number of items per column (forgive the c#):

```
int itemsPerColumn = Model.Posts.Count / 5; // 5 columns on our page

if (Model.Posts.Count % 5 > 0) {
    itemsPerColumn++; // so 8 articles would yield 2 per column
}
```

We then loop through each article and increment a counter.

If `i % itemsPerColumn == 0` we create an opening column div.

After rendering the item we check if `(i + 1) % itemsPerColumn == 0` and if so render a closing column div.

Then we increment the counter.

Not quite as nice as the CSS3 solution but it works :)

Comment: Don't just paste the entire code into the HTML box: http://jsfiddle.net/uDAJy/1/

Comment: My bad, I've updated the link in my question.

Comment: Do the list items have a fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    border:2px solid red;
    height:604px;
    width:464px;
    padding:16px;
    -webkit-column-width:144px;
    -webkit-column-gap:16px;
    -moz-column-width:144px;
    -moz-column-gap:16px;
    column-width:144px;
    column-gap:16px;
}

.wrapper li { 
    width:144px;
    height:108px;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:16px 0;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uDAJy/5/show/

This should work in all browsers except IE. (I only have Chrome on my notebook, so I can't test this in the other browsers.)

Comment: thanks. I've created another solution that will work with IE (requires some server side coding) but I can use your CSS3 version for the other browsers.

Comment: @Ben The problem with variable-height items is that they will break into two pieces if they don't perfectly fit into the column (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uDAJy/6/show/). That's why my demo uses fixed dimensions for the wrapper and items. I'm not sure there is a way to tell the browser not to break the items into two pieces, but there might be...

Comment: okay I'll keep that in mind. There are some cases where I can specify a height. When I can't I can use the solution I posted in my answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ben I have addressed this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885401/prevent-element-fragmentation-in-multi-column-layout

Answer (score 2):

This article on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists) demonstrates some of the most acceptable ways of acheiving what you're after.

As far as I know, at the moment, there's no native way to create a multi-column list using a single CSS property etc.

Comment: Perfect, I can remember finding this a few months ago but couldn't remember what site it was or what I had searched :)

Comment: @Jamie What do you mean there isn't? There is the [multi-column layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol) - it's in all browsers except IE.

Comment: Thanks @Sime. I haven't read that document. Like I said "As far as I know".

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/uDAJy/2/

If you can target browsers that support CSS 3 column-count.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/