# Prevent splitting inner divs while using column-width property

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a multi-column layout while still holding the "inner divs" together.
Line-height property does a good job stacking divs on top of each other but splits my inner divs in half.

The columns does not have to be exactly the same height.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="c">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
</div>

.c {
  -webkit-column-width:250px; -webkit-column-gap:10px;
  -moz-column-width:250px; -moz-column-gap:10px;
  column-width:250px; column-gap:10px;
  color:white;
}

.c > div:nth-child(1) { height:100px; background-color:grey; }
.c > div:nth-child(2) { height:200px; background-color:blue; }
.c > div:nth-child(3) { height:100px; background-color:red; }
.c > div:nth-child(4) { height:100px; background-color:yellow; }
.c > div:nth-child(5) { height:100px; background-color:black; }
.c > div:nth-child(6) { height:100px; background-color:orange; }
```

See example below
http://jsfiddle.net/D73pD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
```

for each `div` element

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/D73pD/1/

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885401/prevent-element-fragmentation-in-multi-column-layout)